# Android gradle error when sync style attribute not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting a few errors when I try to sync gradle. I am extremely new to android coding.

**Gradle Console**

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:clean
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug
:app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/roundSelector (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/roundSelector)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\adend\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Timetable\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles_parent.xml","position":{"startLine":32,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1268,"endLine":59,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":2471}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/rectSelector (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/rectSelector)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\adend\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Timetable\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles_parent.xml","position":{"startLine":32,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1268,"endLine":59,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":2471}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/rectSelectorStrong (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/rectSelectorStrong)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\adend\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Timetable\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles_parent.xml","position":{"startLine":32,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1268,"endLine":59,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":2471}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/defaultFooterColor (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/defaultFooterColor)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\adend\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Timetable\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles_parent.xml","position":{"startLine":32,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1268,"endLine":59,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":2471}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/dividerColor (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/dividerColor)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\adend\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Timetable\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles_parent.xml","position":{"startLine":32,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1268,"endLine":59,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":2471}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/iconColor (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/iconColor)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\adend\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Timetable\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles_parent.xml","position":{"startLine":32,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1268,"endLine":59,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":2471}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/toolbarPopupTheme (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/toolbarPopupTheme)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\adend\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Timetable\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles_parent.xml","position":{"startLine":32,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":1268,"endLine":59,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":2471}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/roundSelector (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/roundSelector)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\adend\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Timetable\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":81,"endColumn":56,"endOffset":133}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/rectSelector (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/rectSelector)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\adend\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Timetable\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":81,"endColumn":56,"endOffset":133}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/rectSelectorStrong (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/rectSelectorStrong)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\adend\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Timetable\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":81,"endColumn":56,"endOffset":133}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/defaultFooterColor (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/defaultFooterColor)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\adend\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Timetable\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":81,"endColumn":56,"endOffset":133}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/dividerColor (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/dividerColor)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\adend\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Timetable\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":81,"endColumn":56,"endOffset":133}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/iconColor (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/iconColor)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\adend\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Timetable\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":81,"endColumn":56,"endOffset":133}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/toolbarPopupTheme (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/toolbarPopupTheme)\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\adend\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Timetable\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\styles.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":81,"endColumn":56,"endOffset":133}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
C:\Users\adend\AndroidStudioProjects\Timetable\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2895: error: style attribute 'attr/roundSelector (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/roundSelector)' not found.
C:\Users\adend\AndroidStudioProjects\Timetable\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2896: error: style attribute 'attr/rectSelector (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/rectSelector)' not found.
C:\Users\adend\AndroidStudioProjects\Timetable\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2897: error: style attribute 'attr/rectSelectorStrong (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/rectSelectorStrong)' not found.
C:\Users\adend\AndroidStudioProjects\Timetable\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2901: error: style attribute 'attr/defaultFooterColor (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/defaultFooterColor)' not found.
C:\Users\adend\AndroidStudioProjects\Timetable\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2903: error: style attribute 'attr/dividerColor (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/dividerColor)' not found.
C:\Users\adend\AndroidStudioProjects\Timetable\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2904: error: style attribute 'attr/iconColor (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/iconColor)' not found.
C:\Users\adend\AndroidStudioProjects\Timetable\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2906: error: style attribute 'attr/toolbarPopupTheme (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/toolbarPopupTheme)' not found.
C:\Users\adend\AndroidStudioProjects\Timetable\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2923: error: style attribute 'attr/roundSelector (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/roundSelector)' not found.
C:\Users\adend\AndroidStudioProjects\Timetable\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2924: error: style attribute 'attr/rectSelector (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/rectSelector)' not found.
C:\Users\adend\AndroidStudioProjects\Timetable\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2925: error: style attribute 'attr/rectSelectorStrong (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/rectSelectorStrong)' not found.
C:\Users\adend\AndroidStudioProjects\Timetable\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2929: error: style attribute 'attr/defaultFooterColor (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/defaultFooterColor)' not found.
C:\Users\adend\AndroidStudioProjects\Timetable\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2931: error: style attribute 'attr/dividerColor (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/dividerColor)' not found.
C:\Users\adend\AndroidStudioProjects\Timetable\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2932: error: style attribute 'attr/iconColor (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/iconColor)' not found.
C:\Users\adend\AndroidStudioProjects\Timetable\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2934: error: style attribute 'attr/toolbarPopupTheme (aka com.example.adend.timetable:attr/toolbarPopupTheme)' not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor397.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
    at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

14 actionable tasks: 11 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.adend.timetable"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '27.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-ui:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-fragment:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:percent:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:preference-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:preference-v14:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation 'com.github.kabouzeid:app-theme-helper:1.3.7'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad:material-cab:0.1.12'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Light" parent="Theme.Base.Light" />

    <style name="Theme.Dark" parent="Theme.Base.Dark" />


    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**v21/styles.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.Dark" parent="Theme.Base.Dark">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Light" parent="Theme.Base.Light">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>
```

**styles_parent.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Base.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

        <item name="md_dark_theme">true</item>

        <item name="roundSelector">@drawable/round_selector_dark</item>
        <item name="rectSelector">@drawable/rect_selector_dark</item>
        <item name="rectSelectorStrong">@drawable/rect_selector_strong_dark</item>

        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/md_grey_800</item>

        <item name="defaultFooterColor">@color/md_grey_900</item>

        <item name="dividerColor">@color/md_divider_white</item>
        <item name="iconColor">@color/ate_secondary_text_dark</item>

        <item name="toolbarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat</item>

        <!-- just in case-->
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>

        <!-- necessary to find the overflow button later in the layout-->
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow</item>

        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Base.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

        <item name="md_dark_theme">false</item>

        <item name="roundSelector">@drawable/round_selector</item>
        <item name="rectSelector">@drawable/rect_selector</item>
        <item name="rectSelectorStrong">@drawable/rect_selector_strong</item>

        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/md_white_1000</item>

        <item name="defaultFooterColor">@color/md_grey_300</item>

        <item name="dividerColor">@color/md_divider_black</item>
        <item name="iconColor">@color/ate_secondary_text_light</item>

        <item name="toolbarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>

        <!-- just in case-->
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/black</item>

        <!-- necessary to find the overflow button later in the layout-->
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow</item>

        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
    </style>

    <!-- content description is necessary to find the overflow button later in the layout-->
    <style name="Widget.ActionButton.Overflow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/abc_action_menu_overflow_description</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**first bit of values.xml (limited on characters, but don't worry it hasn't been touched)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <attr format="reference" name="constraintSet"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="drawerArrowStyle"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="height"/>
    <attr format="boolean" name="isLightTheme"/>
    <attr format="integer" name="layout_constraintBaseline_creator"/>
    <attr format="reference|enum"
```

Also, I am getting 2 error on values.xml:

`URI is not registered`

and

`Resource registered by this URI is not recognized`

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Your Error Log seems Like you are getting this error because of

> error: style attribute 'attr/roundSelector (aka
>   com.example.adend.timetable:attr/roundSelector)' not found.

So Please check this

> @drawable/round_selector_dark

you have this **round_selector_dark** in your drawable or not .

there are multiple errors and all are regarding your **style.xml**

So double check your style.xml elements.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this following error: **AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: style attribute \u0027attr/preferenceTheme (aka com.example.android.project:attr/preferenceTheme)\u0027 not found.", ... }**

Then I figured, since I was not using the **PreferenceFragmentCompat**, I had removed a seemingly unnecessary dependency  from by build.gradle: '**com.android.support:preference-v4:27.1.1**' I have put that dependency back and am feeling lonely as ever again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two or more libraries in a project, this isssue could be raised by depended library.

For me, Project *A* contains library *B* and *C*, and each of which library has Logger library *L*.

The error raised in library *B* while doing `mergeReleaseResources` task, but the root cause was laid on library *L*. In detail, the library *L* had meaningless `style` definitions. I removed style items and the issue resolved.